# Problem with facebook login from the facebook application

Tags: facebook, authentication, mobile

I also encounter a problem with a project, login with facebook works on absolutely any browser, even those on mobile, but in the integrated browser in the facebook application it doesn't work, it just doesn't connect me, it sends me back to login ... can you help me with a piece of advice please? Thank you.

I used this script:

```js
    <script>
        (function(){
            var body = $('body');

            var socialLoginErrorElm = $('#loginError');
            var loginModal = $('#loginModal');

            body.on('social-login:error', function(e, error) {
                socialLoginErrorElm.removeClass('hide').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
                loginModal.removeClass("logging-in");
            });
            window.loginWithFb = function(){
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        if(response.authResponse.grantedScopes.split(',').indexOf('email') < 0) {
                            //If email permission not granted
                            body.trigger('social-login:error', (__('fbNoEmailError')));
                            return;
                        }
                        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email'}, function(response) {
                            console.log('Logged in as ' + response.name + '.');
                            //Dual check email - needed to if check if the user has a verified email ID
                            if(!response.email) {
                                body.trigger('social-login:error', (__('fbNoEmailError')));
                                return;
                            }
                            body.trigger('loggedIn:fb');
                        });
                    } else {
                        body.trigger('social-login:error', (__('fbPermissionError')));
                    }
                }, {
                    scope: 'email',
                    auth_type: 'rerequest',
                    'return_scopes': true
                });
            }
            
            var body = $('body');
            body.on('click', '[data-action="loginWithFB"]', function(e){
                loginWithFb();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            body.on('loggedIn', function(){
                loginModal.modal('hide');
            });
            body.on('loggedIn:fb', function(){
                if(!User.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $.get(BASE_PATH + '/login/fb').success(function(response){
                        User.setData(response.user);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        body.trigger('social-login:error', jqXHR.responseText);
                    }).always(function(){
                        loginModal.removeClass("logging-in");
                    });
                }
            });
            body.on('prompt-login', function(e, message){
                loginModal.find('.login-prompt-message').html(message);
                loginModal.modal('show');
            });
        })();

        function showNewPointsAlert(addedPoints) {
            var alertOptions = {
                title: "+"+ addedPoints +" " + __('points'),
                text: __('earnedNewPointsMessage'),
                imageUrl: "{{LeaderboardHelpers::getPointsIcon()}}",
                confirmButtonText: __('earnedNewPointsOkayBtnText'),
                allowEscapeKey: true,
                allowOutsideClick: true,
                customClass: 'new-points-alert'
            }
            @if(!empty($mainBtnColor))
            alertOptions.confirmButtonColor = '{{{$mainBtnColor}}}';
            @endif
            swal(alertOptions);
        }
        $('body').on('user-activity-recorded', function() {
            $.get('{{route('getMyPoints')}}').success(function(response) {
                if(response && response.points) {
                    var oldPoints = parseInt(User.data.points);
                    var newPoints = parseInt(response.points);
                    User.data.points = newPoints;
                    User.setData(User.data);
                    if(oldPoints != newPoints) {
                        var animateClass = 'animated bounceIn';
                        $('#headerUserMenu').removeClass(animateClass).addClass(animateClass);
                        var addedPoints = parseInt(newPoints) - parseInt(oldPoints);
                        @if(MyConfig::isTrue('leaderboard.showNewPointsAlert'))
                        showNewPointsAlert(addedPoints);
                        @endif
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function() {

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I specify that only on the Facebook application on android it doesn't work, on the facebook application on ios it works perfectly ...

Comment: Update: On facebook lite for android work fine...

Comment: https://youtu.be/uyZDeQt6t80 this is problem... I also noticed that there are several sites that I can't connect with on facebook